# Multiple virtual interfaces all bridged to eth0

Tags: vmware, ethernet, bridge

I'm following [this tutorial](http://www.eglug.org/book/export/html/3439) for setting up bridged a bridged Ethernet interface using `uml-utilities` and `bridge-utils` and it works for 2 interfaces but no more than 2.

What I'm trying to achieve is the sort of VirtualBox style bridging where you can have many different interfaces all with their own assigned IP from the router.

Ideally I'd want something like this:

```
eth0 - 192.168.1.12 -- host IP
tap0 - 192.168.1.13 -- ip of first virtual adapter
tap1 - 192.168.1.14
...
```

Where I'm getting hung up on is this, when I try to add `eth0` to be part of `br1`, as well as `br0`.

```
~ # brctl addif br1 eth0
device eth0 is already a member of a bridge; can't enslave it to bridge br1.
```

Other commands:

```
~ # brctl show
bridge name bridge id       STP enabled interfaces
br0     8000.3209ba59de51   no      eth0
                                    tap0
br1     8000.000000000000   no
```

`br0` *has* an IP,  it's different from what `eth0` used to have. `eth0` *does not have* an IP, since I ran the command `sudo ifconfig eth0 0.0.0.0 promisc` from [the tutorial](http://www.eglug.org/book/export/html/3439).  `tap0` *does not* have an ip.

---

I can bring `eth0`'s IP back, if I do a `dhclient eth0` and it becomes what it previously was, different from `br0`'s current IP.

Comment: an interface cannot be a member of multiple bridges.

Comment: Perhaps it is possible to bridge different vlan set on the same interface, not exactly the same has having the same eth on multiple bridges. I think that's what the *wrt are doing (router embedded linux distribs).